# how to use min-height in child element with percentage?

Tags: html, css, height

I wanted to render HTML according to #child_2's contents
(https://jsfiddle.net/xhtp70e6/)

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="child_1"></div>
        <div id="child_2">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>

html, body { height: 100%; }
#parent { width: 50px; height: 1px; min-height: 100%; }
#child { width: 50px; height: 1px; min-height: 80%; background-color: blue; }    
#child_1 { height: 50%; background-color: black; }
#child_2 { min-height: 50%;  background-color: pink; }
#child2 { width: 50px; height: 20%;  background-color: orange; }
```

when the contents's short, a document is rendered fully to page well. (like above example)

but when the contents's long, it doesn't display whole #child_2's contents.  (https://jsfiddle.net/mrdkvvbn/)
The #child2's contents goes up on the #child_2's contents without going down it.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="child_1"></div>
        <div id="child_2">Content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

How can I solve it? please help me !

Comment: use display:flex;

Comment: @peter Thanks!!, I want to know which element I use display flex to.. If you know answer, tell me that please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set a min-height on the body instead of height..

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
```

I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oro2434d/

Comment: You have "heigh: 1px;" on #parent and #child - this is erroneous css which should be removed.  Other than that, good answer.  The &nbsp; in child_1 and child2 is important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but is it impossible to set the child_1's height to 50%?, I think your answer's child_1's height just display &nbsp;'s height..